# Automatically update code to Java 5

Tags: java

I have a lot of Java 1.4 code, which I'm in the process of migrating to Java 5. I would like to fix all the compiler warnings about using raw types in parameterized classes, and am wondering if there is a tool that can automatically transform something like:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("foo");
String foo = (String) myList.get(0);
```

to:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("foo");
String foo = myList.get(0);
```

I understand that Generics are quite complex and therefore don't expect that such a tool would be able to choose the most correct parameterized type in all cases. However, as long as it can handle simple cases (such as the above), and won't break my code, I'll be satisfied.

Similarly, I would like to change all the old-skool loops, to the simplified for loop introduced in Java 5.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Sounds like a time to refactor to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do this using Eclipse.

Select the package structure you need to be upgraded, then right click -> Refactor -> Infer Generic Type Arguments

Imho it's a starting point for what you need.

Comment: Also you can turn on Eclipse warnings for generics so you can easily see where such refactorings could occur.

Answer (score -2):

I think the safest thing for you to do is have a @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") annotation for your methods. Since your code is already tested to work in 1.4 (i assume) and having generic like syntax inserted that way can cause some nasty bugs to come up. 
You can have other [values](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/supported-values-for-suppresswarnings/) for suppresswarnings.

You can also add this annotation to a class

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") 
public class MyClass {}
```

Although i can't think of a tool to do that.

As for the for loop, using the new "for" loop makes sense when you are writing new code. Because its easier. Why change the old style loop? Come on, its not that bad a syntax and certainly not that hard to understand either :)

Comment: What's "safe" about suppressing warnings?

Comment: How could nasty bugs arise? It shouldn't affect the bytecode, so apart from accidentally messing the code up with auto-complete while adding generics, I can't really think of how you could embed bugs by adding generics. If you do something wrong, it'll be compile time error, so you'll notice it (and that's all it does).

Comment: My gut feeling is that by adding generics, you're more likely to discover a bug than create one, as long as you are careful and have lots of unit tests (and perhaps write more as you go).

Comment: Haha! Good one, but ironically its probably safer than to have generic like syntax inserted. Only god knows where those collections are being passed around.

Comment: @naikus - I want to update my code to use generic types, rather than just suppressing the compiler warnings. Also, because of type-erasure, I don't think there's any time a runtime error could be introduced (though it is possible to introduce a compile-time error).